# Turning off Ads using Facebook Marketing API v2.9 in Python

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-marketing-api

I've been struggling on turning off Facebook Ads that are not performing well inside an Adset using Python and the Facebook marketing API. I'm a little bit concerned about the number of access that my code does to the API. Another concern is that I'm using 'get_insights' method to have access to the parameters that I want to use to build a logical decision, but I need to use 'get_ads' to be able to turn them on/off, so I feel that I'm doing things doubled.
Here's an example of what I've been doing so far using the API v2.9:

```
from facebookads.api import FacebookAdsApi
from facebookads import adobjects
from facebookads.adobjects.adaccount import *
from facebookads.adobjects.campaign import *
from facebookads.adobjects.adset import *
from facebookads.adobjects.ad import *
from fctn import * # this is just a file where I centralized some functions
import credentials
import copy

# Auth
my_app_id = credentials.my_app_id
my_app_secret = credentials.my_app_secret
my_access_token = credentials.my_access_token
api = FacebookAdsApi.init(my_app_id, my_app_secret, my_access_token)

ad_account = AdAccount(credentials.ad_account)

# Batch creation
my_batch = api.new_batch()

# Desired fields
fields = ['campaign_name', 'adset_name', 'ad_name', 'ctr', 'impressions']

# Getting all Adsets
ad_sets = ad_account.get_ad_sets(fields=[AdSet.Field.name, Ad.Field.created_time, Ad.Field.status],
    params={
        'effective_status': ['ACTIVE'],
        'date_preset': 'last_30d',
        'limit': 5000})

# We'll iterate over each adset because we want to campare just the ads inside the same adset       
for ad_set in ad_sets:

    ads = ad_set.get_ads(fields=[Ad.Field.name, Ad.Field.created_time, Ad.Field.status],
                              params={'effective_status': ['ACTIVE'],
                                      'date_preset': 'last_30d',
                                 'limit': 5000})

    ads_insights = ad_set.get_insights(fields=fields,
                              params={'level': 'ad',
                                      'date_preset': 'last_30d',
                                 'effective_status': ['ACTIVE'],
                                 'limit': 5000})

    # this is an external funtion to get the median in relation with some metric
    median_ctr = median_metric(ads_insights, 'ctr')

    print(median_ctr)
    print(ads_insights[0]['campaign_name'])
    print(ad_set['name'])
    print('BEFORE')
    print(ads)

    for i in range(0, len(ads)):

        if dias_ate_hoje(ads[i]['created_time'][:10]) < 10:
            # If Ad running less than 10 days, keep going
            continue
        else:
            if float(ads_insights[i]['impressions']) < 300:
                # If impressions less then 300, keep going (just an arbitrary decision here)
                continue
            else:
                if float(ads_insights[i]['ctr']) < median_ctr:
                    # If Ad is in the worst half in relation with CTR: turn off
                    ads[i].api_update(params={'status': 'PAUSED'}, batch=my_batch)
                else:
                    continue

    my_batch.execute()

    print('AFTER')
    print(ads)
```

Hope anyone who had already done something like that could help me making this code better with less access to the API and doubled pieces of code.
Thanks.

Comment: Very nice and clean code! Also I think it's the only concise example of how to use batching api and modifying campaign status. Thank you so much Mauricio!

Comment: But i'm wondering how are you handling batching limits of 50 calls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you can do:

1. Get all ads from account level `ad_account.get_ads()`
2. Get insights from account `ad_account.get_insights(fields=fields,params={'level': 'ad', ...})`

In your insights API calls, you need to add `adset_id` and `ad_id` to `fields`, so that you can calculate adset median ctr and pause ads.

In this way you don't need to loop over adsets and make API calls for each of them. If the insights data is too large, you can try the async insights api https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/insights/best-practices#asynchronous

Comment: Thank you! That's already better. Now I have all ads_insights but they aren't grouped by adset. I was wondering about doing something like:
1. Group them by adset_id;
2. Apply the median;
3. Iterate over that group to get the ad_id of those whom ctr is under the median;
4. Turn off the ads by their id;

That's the way? Sounds like a lot of iterations!
Thanks again.

Comment: Hi Mauricio, that's right. Still a few iterations but they're on the client side so it should be fast and not cause additional network traffic :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, Jiaming! (:

Comment: @Mauricio if possible, can you please share the code to just PAUSE an ad/adset/campaign?